# Запрос на сравнение пар SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Ребята, пытаюсь составить СКУЛ запрос между двумя таблицами.
Суть в чем, есть таблица dialogs в ней есть графа id диалога и две графы user_1 и user_2

есть таблица messages в которой есть графы dialog_id sender_id и receiver_id

мне нужно получить запросом список id-шек диалогов (1-ая таблица) между юзерами у которых НЕТУ еще сообщений. то есть user_1 и user_2 (допустим 22 и 144) парой не присутсвуют в таблице messages как sender_id и receiver_id
то что у кого то из них с другими юезрами есть диалоги и сообщения - это понятно это мы не трогаем. задача выявить "пустые" диалоги в таблице dialogs

[image: dialogs]
[image: messages]

Запрос должен учитывать что user_1 и user_2 из таблицы dialogs в таблице messages могут быть как sender так и receiver, жесткой привязки нет между ними.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT d.id 
FROM dialogs d
LEFT JOIN messages m ON LEAST(d.user_1, d.user_2) = LEAST(m.sender_id, m.receiver_id)
                    AND GREATEST(d.user_1, d.user_2) = GREATEST(m.sender_id, m.receiver_id)
WHERE m.dialog_id IS NULL
```

либо

```sql
...
LEFT JOIN messages m ON (d.user_1, d.user_2) IN ((m.sender_id, m.receiver_id),
                                                 (m.receiver_id, m.sender_id))
...
```

---

Или то же самое, но в виде WHERE NOT EXISTS.

Comment: не понят, причем тут WHERE d.dialog_id IS NULL      он не может быть NULL

Comment: @ДенисПотапов *причем тут WHERE d.dialog_id IS NULL* Дык не я условие "получить не присутствующие" писал. *он не может быть NULL* Не говорите ерунды. Попробуйте прочитать про внешнее связывание **ну хоть что-нибудь**.

Comment: а этот запрос учитывает что user_1 может быть как sender_id так и receiver_id  в таблице messages.  и user_2  тоже.

Comment: попробовал вот так запустить-  SELECT d.id FROM dialogs d LEFT JOIN messages m ON LEAST(d.user_1, d.user_2) = LEAST(m.sender_id, m.receiver_id) AND GREATEST(d.user_1, d.user_2) = GREATEST(m.sender_id, m.receiver_id) WHERE d.dialog_id IS NULL        сразу дает ошибку-   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'd.dialog_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: @ДенисПотапов Блин, ты теперь с каждой опечаткой бегать будешь? Тебе дали ответ - наверное, не просто от фонаря. Так разберись, как он работает, и пойми, почему я считаю, что он решит поставленную задачу. Не можешь понять - задавай конкретные вопросы. Показывающие, что ты пытаешься разобраться.

Comment: ооо пасиб) теперь заработало)))  я так понимаю он все комбинации учитывает? что user1 и user2 могут быть как sender так и receiver